# S3 methods were declared in NAMESPACE but not found for R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to install tidyverse and to load it. While doing so facing the following issue of S3 methods were declared but not found in NAMESPACE

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
 undefined exports: abline, arrows, assocplot, axTicks, Axis, axis, axis.Date, axis.POSIXct, barplot, box, boxplot, bxp, cdplot, clip, close.screen, co.intervals, contour, coplot, curve, dotchart, erase.screen, filled.contour, fourfoldplot, frame, grconvertX, grconvertY, grid, hist, identify, image, layout, layout.show, lcm, legend, lines, locator, matlines, matplot, matpoints, mosaicplot, mtext, pairs, panel.smooth, par, persp, pie, plot.design, plot.function, plot.new, plot.window, plot.xy, points, polygon, polypath, rasterImage, rect, rug, screen, segments, smoothScatter, spineplot, split.screen, stars, stem, strheight, stripchart, strwidth, sunflowerplot, symbols, text, title, xinch, xspline, xyinch, yinch, .filled.contour, barplot.default, boxplot.default, boxplot.matrix, contour.default, hist.default, image.default, lines.default, pairs.default, plot.default, points.default, text.default
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘Axis.default’, ‘Axis.Date’, ‘Axis.POSIXt’, ‘Axis.table’, ‘barplot.default’, ‘barplot.formula’, ‘boxplot.default’, ‘boxplot.formula’, ‘boxplot.matrix’, ‘cdplot.default’, ‘cdplot.formula’, ‘contour.default’, ‘hist.Date’, ‘hist.default’, ‘hist.POSIXt’, ‘identify.default’, ‘image.default’, ‘lines.default’, ‘lines.formula’, ‘lines.histogram’, ‘lines.table’, ‘mosaicplot.default’, ‘mosaicplot.formula’, ‘pairs.default’, ‘pairs.formula’, ‘persp.default’, ‘plot.data.frame’, ‘plot.default’, ‘plot.factor’, ‘plot.formula’, ‘plot.function’, ‘plot.histogram’, ‘plot.raster’, ‘plot.table’, ‘points.default’, ‘points.formula’, ‘points.table’, ‘spineplot.default’, ‘spineplot.formula’, ‘stripchart.default’, ‘stripchart.formula’, ‘sunflowerplot.default’, ‘sunflowerplot.formula’, ‘text.default’, ‘text.formula’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching for an answer, it seemed better to uninstall R and RStudio once again. After that the problem was solved.

Doesn't seem like the correct solution but worked anyhow.